# Start menu won't automatically close after launching program on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

When I open Start menu and launch a program from it with a left click. It stays opened and doesn't automatically close like it used to. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try updating Windows 10. There were a lot of updates yesterday (Patch Tuesday).  Then from an Admin Command Prompt, run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth   followed by SFC /SCANNOW   .   Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: I observe same behavior when my Windows runs a long time without reboot. After couple of week without reboot the start menu either does not close automatically or loses its ability to search when type. Reboot always helped me.